# PySpark: Multiply 2 tables by the column names, sum, and add a constant

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes, trying to multiply multiple columns according to the column names, sum the total of the target columns, and then add a constant as the final values. The purpose/use case of this question is to apply a regression coefficient outcome to a dataframe.

The first dataframe:

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| BB | 2 | 5 | 4 |
| CC | 3 | 4 | 1 |

The second dataframe (target columns & constant. i.e. the coefficient table):

| C | A | B | constant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

My expected output:

| ID | A | B | C | final_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 8 | 18 | 21 | 57 |
| BB | 16 | 45 | 28 | 99 |
| CC | 24 | 36 | 7 | 77 |

To further explain the calculation of the `final_number`: Take the ID `AA` as an example. (1x8)+(2x9)+(3x7)+10 = 57

As I have more than 20 variables in the two tables, I try not to use the code such as `df.withColumn("A", 8*F.col("A"))` one by one. Thank you for your input in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehensions to avoid the need to name columns manually. Note that DO NOT do `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` - because I want to keep the `sum` function from Python.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

output = df1.join(
    df2.toDF(*[i+'_2' for i in df2.columns])
).select(
    'ID',
    *[(F.col(i) * F.col(i + '_2')).alias(i) for i in df1.columns[1:]],
    (sum([F.col(i) * F.col(i + '_2') for i in df1.columns[1:]]) + F.col('constant_2')).alias('final_number')
)

output.show()
+---+---+---+---+------------+
| ID|  A|  B|  C|final_number|
+---+---+---+---+------------+
| AA|  8| 18| 21|          57|
| BB| 16| 45| 28|          99|
| CC| 24| 36|  7|          77|
+---+---+---+---+------------+
```

Comment: Hi @mck thanks for your input. Curious to know: (1) If I only want to take all the features available in df2 (meaning there are some extra features in df1), how should I better modify the code. (2) what does the `*` function there?

Comment: @Blair (1) just change `df1.columns` to `df2.columns` (2) `*` unpacks the list into separate arguments